# How can I highlight to start or end with ctrl+shift+a or ctrl+shift+e in terminal emacs?

Tags: emacs

It is ok in the Cocoa Emacs, but how can I do it in the terminal or iTerm2?

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal window, you can't distinguish between Ctrl-letter and Ctrl-shift-letter. Try to rebind the functions bound to these keys to something that the terminal can handle.